# SQL Batch unable to read file call from another file

Tags: sql, oracle, file

I have the following 3 files

```
\TEST\run.sql
\TEST\REPORT\run 2.sql
\TEST\REPORT\PAGE\insertpage.sql
```

"run 2.sql" contains

```
@.\PAGE\insertpage.sql;
```

The run 2 batch will execute the inserpage batch just fine.

However, run.sql contains

```
@".\REPORT\run 2.sql"
```

It reads run 2 and tries to run insertpage.sql, but can not read the file.

Comment: Are you expecting a script run from another one to be located relative to the parent - rather than from your starting directory? When you run `run 2.sql` successfully, which directory are you in and how do you call it? Where are you and how do you call `run.sql`?

Comment: Paths in SQL*Plus scripts are ALWAYS evaluated relative to your working directory (not the script directory). EXCEPT when you use `@@` instead of `@` - that means to look in the same directory as the calling script. Unfortunately, `@@` does not accept paths in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the space before the is your problem.

Change it from Run 2.sql to Run2.sql  Avoid the space.